# Id returned 1 exit status. C++

Tags: c++, function, void, dev-c++

I'm very new to C++, so I've probably made some really stupid mistakes. But I've looked online to solutions for this error, and I tried all I can think of.

I'm trying to have my whole program in one function, because it's going to be merged with other programs. The id error is the only error I have so far.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;
int ninebooking(int Endor=0, int Naboo=0, int tatooine=0);
int sevenbooking(int Endor=0, int Naboo=0, int tatooine=0);
void BookingSystem(int time, int k);
int time;
int k = 0;

int main() 
{
BookingSystem(time, k);
{
while (k==0)
{
printf("\n\nMeals are served at 9pm and 7pm, please enter what time you would like to book for");
scanf("You have selected to book your meal for %d", &time);
if (time!=7||time!=9)
{
        printf("Sorry, that was an incorrect time");
        time = 0;
}
}
return 0;
}

system ("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated, I've spent a long time trying to fix this on my own with no luck.

Thank you!

Comment: You didn't link with the file that contains the `BookingSystem` function. How did you compile/link your code`? Which IDE are you using on which platform?

Comment: `time!=7||time!=9` again... Unless `time` is a class and you do some funny operator overloading on it, this does not make sense.

Comment: @LogicStuff They'll never get that in the 1st semester.

Comment: You write: _I'm trying to have my whole program in one function, because it's going to be merged with other programs_. That doesn't make sens as it stands here, could you elaborate ?

Comment: I'm using DevC on Win10. Just compiled it with DevC's in build one.

Comment: Because this program is going to be merged with others, it'll be easier to have it as one function. I'm not sure where to put my "main" function. @MichaelWalz

Comment: @LogicStuff It's validation, doesn't it work?

Comment: @Toby Hint: `(time != 7 || time != 9)` is always true.

Comment: @MichaelWalz and LogicStuff Oh, I don't know how I didn't see that. I do apologise.

Comment: Okay, I've edited the code. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: is this code in `main` maybe meant to be the definition of the function `Bookingsystem` ? If that is the case, then no it is not a definition of a function. `BookingSystem(time, k);` calls the function (that is defined nowhere) and then follows some block of code

Comment: `scanf("You have selected to book your meal for %d", &time);` Not invalid, but smells. The user will have to input `You have selected to book your meal for` before inputting the number to be read to `time`.

Comment: @MikeCAT Going to be honest, I really don't understand sorry.

Comment: @tobi303 I've updated it again, is that better?

Comment: better with respect to what? That code is now completely different from what you posted in the beginning. Does this even produce the same error? Questions are not meant to be edited until everybody is happy, but you should post the question and then leave it like it is, because answers and comments will refer to the code as it was when the comment/answer was written. Half of the comments are already obsolete, because you changed the code in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make many mistakes in your program:

1) You mix C & C++ syntax.

**using namespace std,** is C++

2) You include useless header files

3) You declare variables that I don't understand what for

Why do you need this?

int ninebooking(int Endor=0, int Naboo=0, int tatooine=0);
int sevenbooking(int Endor=0, int Naboo=0, int tatooine=0);

You don't use the variables above anywhere !!!!

4) You try to write a function **inside** main (this is not Pascal).

So, if I understand what you want, look at this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void BookingSystem() // this is the function who does all job
{
    int time = 0;

    while ((time != 7) && (time != 9))
    {
        printf("\n\nMeals are served at 9pm and 7pm, please enter what time you would like to book for");
        printf("\nYou have selected to book your meal for ");
        scanf("%d", &time); // read the time
        scanf("%*[^\n]");   // consume all caracters until the newline
        scanf("%*c");       // consume the newline
        if (time == 7)
        {
            printf("You have selected to book your slot at 7PM\n");
        }
        else if (time == 9)
        {
            printf("You have selected to book your slot at 9PM\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("You have selected an incorrect time, please try again\n");
        }

    } // end while
} // end function


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    BookingSystem(); // this is the calling to your function

    return 0;
}
```

If I understand what you want, this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can not to Define Function in to the main ..
you must to do like this...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

int ninebooking(int , int , int );  //just say data type int or ....
int sevenbooking(int , int , int );
void BookingSystem(int , int);

int main() //and in to main just call he...
{
 int time;
 int k = 0;

 BookingSystem(time, k);//call ....and send parameter time and k

 system ("PAUSE");
 return 0;

}

void BookingSystem(int time,int k)
{
    while (k==0)
    {
        printf("\n\nMeals are served at 9pm and 7pm, please enter what time you would like to book for");
        scanf("You have selected to book your meal for %d", &time);
        if (time!=7||time!=9)
        {
            printf("Sorry, that was an incorrect time");
            time = 0;
        }
    }
    //  return 0;//if this function is void he can not to return any thing!!!!
}

int ninebooking(int Endor=0, int Naboo=0, int tatooine=0)
{
    //......
}

int sevenbooking(int Endor=0, int Naboo=0, int tatooine=0)
{
    //........
}
```